# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "pelillos a la mar"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

La pregunta de hoy la ilustro con un extracto de la primera gran aventura de Mortadelo y Filemón: "El sulfato atómico".

[image: Pelillos a la mar]

Efectivamente, "pelillos a la mar" es una frase popular, que significa:

> **[pelillos a la mar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SOP1npb)**
>
> 1. expr. U. para expresar el deseo de olvido de agravios y restablecimiento del trato amistoso.
> 2. expr. U. por los muchachos para afirmar que no faltarán a lo que han tratado y convenido, lo cual hacen arrancándose cada uno un pelo
>      de la cabeza, y soplándolos dicen: Pelillos a la mar.

Curiosamente, en el diccionario se especifica que un "pelillo" es:

> **[pelillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SOP1npb)**
>
> Del dim. de *pelo*.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Causa o motivo muy leve de desazón, y que se debe despreciar. U. m. en pl.

Definición esta que ya existía en el Diccionario de Autoridades de 1737. Así pues, la pregunta podría dividirse en primero ¿por qué un pelo pequeño es una causa leve de desazón? Y en segundo lugar, ¿por qué se deben tirar al mar para olvidarse de ellos?

En el blog "El origen de las expresiones" [se cita](http://origenlenguaje.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/origen-de-la-expresion-pelillos-la-mar.html) que proviene de una canción infantil andaluza que dice así:

> - ¿Adónde va ese pelo?
>   - Al viento.
>   - ¿Y el viento?
>   - A la mar.
>   - Pues ya la guerra está acabá.

Y continúa diciendo que "se cree que el acto simbólico en sí proviene del relato de La Ilíada, en el que se narra que después del conflicto entre griegos y troyanos [...] en los banquetes tras sus guerras, sacrificaron a los dioses corderos a los que cortaron pelos que arrojaron al mar como muestra de reconciliación".

No sé si me termina de convencer esta explicación, ¿alguien dispone de alguna más convincente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues aparte de la referencia que propones en la pregunta, yo he encontrado además [esta](http://aliso.pntic.mec.es/agalle17/cultura_clasica/entre_dichos/pelillos.html) y [esta](http://www.fraseshechas.net/pelillos-a-la-mar/) apuntando al mismo origen. Por supuesto es dificil saber si son tres articulos "independientes" que citan el mismo origen (correcto) para la expresión o si unos se hacen referencia a los otros.

Pero tambien he encontrado [esta entrada](http://www.yorokobu.es/el-origen-de-los-dichos-pelillos-a-la-mar/), que ya matiza un poco más un posible origen (enfásis mio)

> Cuando decimos ‘pelillos a la mar’ estamos hablando de reconciliación, de olvidar rencillas. Así lo hacen los niños en Andalucía –o lo hacían- **según cuentan Rodrigo Caro en sus *Días geniales o lúdricos*, allá por el siglo XVII y Francisco Rodríguez Marín en *Cantos populares españoles (1882)***. Ambos autores, andaluces para más señas, explican que los chavales hacían las paces cortándose un par de pelillos y echándolos al viento para que se los llevara al mar, simbolizando de esta manera que al igual que el aire se lleva los pelos, hará también lo propio con los agravios y las peleas. ¡Bendita inocencia! Con lo fácil que parece firmar la paz desde los ojos de un niño y lo complicado que lo hacemos cuando crecemos. En fin, sigamos…
>
> Es **el propio Caro quien nos explica que el origen de esa infantil reconciliación se encuentra en el pasaje de La Ilíada en el que se juntan troyanos y griegos para hacer las paces** tras el mal rollito creado entre Helena, Paris y Menelao por un problemilla de cuernos.

[Este otro blog](http://www.1de3.es/2004/07/31/pelillos-mar/) señala al mismo origen: Un juego de niños que ya describe   Rodríguez Marín en su obra Cantos populares españoles y la misma referencia a la Iliada:

> A los corderos que se sacrifican para el banquete, les cortaron simbólicamente unos pelillos que lanzaron al viento y hacia el mar, como señal de que todo quedaba olvidado entre ellos y se restablecía el trato amistoso.

He encontrado tambien [un video (audio)](https://youtu.be/ASvQaV5UPvs?t=267) de un programa de Onda Cero en le que le preguntan a la gente de la calle si saben lo que significan ciertas expresiones. Esperaba poder así "parasitar" la investigación hecha por este programa sobre el origen de la expresión, pero el resultado ha sido decepcionante. Aluden primero a la misma referencia del juego de niños en la Andalucía del siglo XVII para hacer las paces, y luego un poco de refilón a la otra historia andaluza del barbero. Los autores de este programa no mencionan la referencia a la Iliada (pero tampoco creo que hagan una investigación muy rigurosa solo para esta sección de su programa).

Así que lo más que he podido hacer es validar que la referencia al juego/canto de niños tiene cierta validez al encontrarse ya en referenciada en esas obras de Rodrigo Caro y Francisco Rodríguez Marín.

La referencia de la Iliada, aunque me gusta, no me termina de cuadrar. La Iliada es una obra muy antigua y de gran impacto cultural. Si de verdad fuese ese el origen de la expresión, otros idiomas que ha derivado del latín o sufrido las mismas influencias de la cultura griega como el nuestro (es decir, que tienen las mismas raíces) tendrían a su vez una expresión igual o muy similar.

Así que de tener que apostar, yo apostaría por que tiene el origen que mencionas en la pregunta. Acerca del significado de *un pelo* y del mar, como dice este blog, los pelos **son tenidos por poca cosa**

> ¿Y por qué el mar? Porque el viento más pronto o más tarde lleva los pelillos a los arroyos, los ríos o finalmente al mar, que representa la inmensidad de lo indistinto, el gran asimilador de la individualidad. Así nos lo recuerdan los poetas:
>
> Nuestras vidas son los ríos
>
> que van a dar en la mar,
>
> que es el morir…
>
> (Jorge Manrique)

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! Curiosamente, el Diccionario de Autoridades de la RAE recoge la expresión "pelitos a la mar" y también dice que proviene de un juego o canción infantil.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, por cierto, una vez oí que el origen de "_salvarse por los pelos_" es porque antiguamente no todos los marineros sabían nadar y era conveniente llevar el cabello largo para poder ser, literalmetne, alzado de nuevo a bordo por el cabello en caso de caer al agua. He intentado, sin exito, comprobar si había algun tipo de relación entre las dos expresiones que arrojase algo mas de luz sobre "pelillos...":L http://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/icual-es-el-origen-del-dicho-salvarse-por-los-pelos

Answer (score 0):

De [esta entrada de blog](http://www.erroreshistoricos.com/curiosidades-historicas/origen/1257-origen-de-pelillos-a-la-mar.html):

> "Todos hemos escuchado o utilizado en alguna ocasión la expresión "Pelillos a la mar" en las situaciones en las que tenemos que reconciliarnos con alguna persona después de una disputa o riña.
>
> Para conocer el origen de esta expresión hay que remontarse al siglo XVI, y si tenemos que buscar el lugar, hay que ir hasta la ciudad andaluza de Málaga, lugar donde había un hombre que siempre iba a cortarse el pelo al mismo barbero. Acción que repitió durante años hasta el día en el que el peluquero  y barbero decidió dar el salto y emigrar a América.
>
> El hombre, al ver que ya no podría volver a cortarse el pelo llevo su enfado al extremo de retirar el saludo al que había sido su barbero durante gran parte de su vida, al que consideraba no solo peluquero, sino amigo. Al cortador de pelo no le gusto aquello, y trató de arreglar en lo posible la situación enviando a su cliente a un nuevo peluquero. Aquello no sirvió, el despechado cliente jamás consiguió ver en el nuevo peluquero al anterior y dejo de ir.
>
> El problema fue entonces para el nuevo peluquero. Resultó que como no consiguió llevarse bien con el nuevo cliente empezó a perder incluso a los que cortaba el pelo antes porque el "despechado" comenzó a hacerle publicidad en contra diciendo que el barbero guardaba el pelo cortado y con el hacía brujería a todos los que no pagaban a tiempo.
>
> El peluquero acabo cerrando el negocio al quedarse sin clientes y a la ver reto al hombre que tanto daño le había hecho a batirse en duelo. Eligio para el duelo como arma el florete.
>
> En el duelo el cliente, que casi murió, se dió cuenta del mal que había hecho y pidió perdón al barbero. Aquello le unió tanto que tomaron la decisión de ir a las Américas llevándose todo el pelo almacenado para porder tirarlo en la travesía como símbolo del comienzo de una nueva vida."

Comment: Kohoh, gracias por tu respuesta. De todos modos, ¿qué información de esta entrada de blog te hace pensar que es más verosímil que la que apunta Carlos Alejo en su enunciado?